# Appium + Selenium - Unable to locate element on native app after popup closed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am testing a native app using Appium + Selenium + Java.

The scenario is there is a popup which gets opened up on screen. Once the popup is closed I am unable to navigate back to the screen on which popup was opened.

Driver isn't able to locate it.

I tried this so far...

Returning Page object from PopupOk call
`driver.switchto()` - Everything in this, frames, `defaultContent()`
`driver.context(name)`
but nothing works.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the relevant lines of code and the error stack trace please?

Comment: Are you saying that the screen has changed after the popup has been closed, or that it's the same screen but your locators do not work?  Are you using page objects?  If so, re-create the page object.

Comment: @BillHileman - I am on the same screen but locators are not working. I tried recreating page objects but even that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me: ((***Appium 1.10, Android 8.1***))

2 options:

**1st solution:**

```
driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofMillis(300));
```

After you close your popUp, you use this line and your app will go to background and back and you will get back the focus to your app.

**2nd solution:**   better one :)

Add this line to settings:

```
capability.setCapability("noReset", true);
```

From now your app will start like normal app, without setting reset what means without pop-ups and you will not have problem with focus at all.

I hope it will work also for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try getting your app focus again by sending it to background for 0 secs?

Try this just after popup is closed:

```
driver.runAppInBackground(0);
```

If it works you will have to be able to resume your test normally

Comment: Sorry for late reply. There were some issues with environment. I tried but when app comes in foreground it start with home page and doesn't open the page where I was on.